# edit text saving status in android

Tags: android

i did a lot of trials before coming here, i need that user find the same values entered in

an activity when he returns to , i did this code but it is not working :

```
             public class ActivityUn extends Activity {
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("arm_1", rm_1ts);
    savedInstanceState.putString("arm_2", rm_2ts);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
    public void  ajouter(View v) {
           db.open();
               long id =  db.insertMENAGE(rm_1ts,rm_2ts); }
 EditText  rm_1;
EditText  rm_2;
 String rm_1ts = "";
 String rm_2ts = "";
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_un);

            rm_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_1);
    rm_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.rm_2);
     if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            rm_1ts = savedInstanceState.getString("arm_1");
            rm_2ts = savedInstanceState.getString("arm_2");
            rm_1.setText(rm_1ts);
            rm_2.setText(rm_2ts);
        }
         Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajoutUn);
         bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
               @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                  rm_1ts = rm_1.getText().toString();
                  rm_2ts = rm_2.getText().toString();
             ajouter(v);

             }
          });
```

Comment: where have you initialized EditText?

Comment: first i create variables in Activity, and inside Oncreate i make relation to the views, i think the issue comes here, because rm_1ts has no value at first, and inside onClik i associated to the values entered by user.

Comment: Exactly. First initialize it otherwise how do you know which `EditText` you are referring to? Your `onsaveInstanceState` is just fine. You can check the value via `Log` or `Toast`.

Comment: that's a good idea for test, thanks my friend :)

Comment: nothing change, even the toast is not displayed, i verified the code is correct but why is not working!!!

Comment: i added the code related to EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `onSaveInstanceState` is only called when your `Activity` is killed via System to free memory or a 3rd party app. But when you press a back button in an `Activity` it simply  is equivalent to `finish()`. In this case `onSaveInstanceState` is not called. So if you want to store data every time your `Activity` is created just store the values in a `SharedPreference`. You can store the values either in `onStop` or `onPause` method depending on your needs.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) you can learn more about SharedPrefence and other types of storage options.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, you could store the value in the `SharedPreferences`.

```
getSharedPreferences().edit().putString("myEditText", yourValue).commit();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring the state in onStart or onResume instead of onCreate.  onCreate is only called if the activity needs to be recreated after it is destroyed.  Often the activity will be retained in the background in a stopped state, and won't call onCreate when it comes back.

Anywhere in your file, put:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding, where to put onResume method, please more details, i would be grateful :)

Comment: i will try it and tell you results.